# convert a Array.filter callback to a recursive function

Tags: reactjs

First of all sorry the messy code and this is the first time I'm posting a question!

So I'm using react-ui-tree. I need to implement a recursive function which goes deep into the tree and changes certain boolean values so that only one node(which is toggled) remains open/close while toggled the collapse button.

At the moment the callback function I'm passing to Array.filter is not checking recursively deep into the tree.(I just manually made it work)
If anyone could give me a solution on how to turn this handleNesting function to a recursive function.

```js
toggleCollapse = nodeId => {
    const tree = this.state.tree;
    const index = tree.getIndex(nodeId);
    const node = index.node;
    node.collapsed = !node.collapsed;
    const handleNesting = (parent) => {

     
      if (parent.children && parent.children.find(inner => inner.ID === 
  node.ID)) {
        parent.collapsed = false
        parent.children.filter(inner => {
          if (inner.ID !== node.ID) inner.collapsed = true;
          
          return inner;
        });
      }
      if (parent.ID !== node.ID && parent.children && !parent.children.find(inner => inner.ID === node.ID)){ 
        parent.collapsed = true
        return parent;
      }

      return parent
    }

    tree.obj.children.filter(handleNesting) //  collapses all the 
   //opened folder except the one which has been toggled(including its //parent folder)
```